# Printing complex widgets in Qt

Tags: qt, printing, qt4

I have a complex widget with tons of different subwidgets, e.g. subclasses of QLabel. I want to print this widget, but obviously I do not want to print the background, I want to print with differing text colors or have the style of frames slightly modified.

As I do not really want to iterate through all subwidgets with a special "print" function, which I would need to attach to all widgets (how to add "print" to a QLabel?), I would like to use paintEvent.

If I have a hierarchy MyWidget -> derived from -> some QWidget, I would like to insert a sublayer MyWidget -> MyPrintWidget -> some QWidget, where myPrintWidget::paintEvent would check, if the current print is going to the screen (thus call QWidget::paintEvent), else if we are printing to the printer, call some function MyPrintWidget::drawWidget instead.

1. Is this the right way to
   print-enable a widget?
2. How can I figure out in
   paintEvent, that I'm printing to a
   printer instead of the screen?
3. Is there a good example of
   printing complex widgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is this the right way to print-enable a widget?

[QWidget::render()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html#render) will render a widget and all of its children to a [QPaintDevice](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qpaintdevice.html), which a [QPrinter](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qprinter.html) is.  For printing, all you need to do is set the [widgets stylesheet](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/stylesheet.html) correctly before calling render on the printer device. You should be able to set it back immediately afterwards if you're reusing an on-screen widget.

> 2. How can I figure out in paintEvent, that I'm printing to a printer instead of the screen?

You might be able to figure it out by looking at the various QPaintDevice properties, but I'd try to avoid relying on that functionality.

> 3. Is there a good example of printing complex widgets?

I don't know of anything that does what you're attempting to do.

Comment: The project is not using stylesheets, so I need to set palettes for printing and have to do the layout manually.