# Qt - Print widgets in specific layout

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qpainter, qprinter

In my project I have some own widgets.
When I click on a toolbar-button to print, I want to print the widgets in a 
specific layout  (landscape-orientation).

I tried it with a new QWidget with a layout, and in this layout add my widgets.
But when I do this, my widget disappear from my mainwindow.

How can I print my widget without disappearing and my own layout?

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean saying "print widgets"?

Comment: Widgets are unique objects, and can only be under one parent at a time. You don't provide much detail, but it's probably best to duplicate the widgets for printing. If you use separate models and views, then models don't need to be duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had asked something similar - [Printing complex widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017351/printing-complex-widgets-in-qt)

and basically ended up in some design, where I set up an invisible copy of the whole widget and caused it to resize on the best size for the print job - take portrait and landscape printing into consideration!

I had to add code to paint- and resize- related methods of my custom widgets, where depending if I was printing or painting to screen, I modified palettes, font sizes, style sheets etc. Modifiying palettes might be necessary if your printer is black/white only. Or if your application has a dark background, you might want to flip colours.

This was quite a tedious job, but you will notice, that customers often don't want a screen hardcopy but something better.